# How to check missing words from one column to other multiple columns using FuzzyWuzzy?

Tags: python, fuzzy-logic, fuzzywuzzy, fuzzy-comparison

I have a column `item_composition` which contains different items and I want to check if words from `item composition` are available in another 3 column for ex A,B .

| item_composition | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Stearic acid ; zinc ; Pentaerythritol | Pentaerythritol | None |

Example sheet : [Example Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QZ751WiGf27O8OPanq35KxKutY3fI_vZN0zLiIKoKb4/edit?usp=sharing)

In above table `Stearic acid ; zinc`  is not available in both A and B column so I should print `Stearic acid ; zinc` in output

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from fuzzywuzzy import process, fuzz
ramen = pd.read_excel('Material_composition_costdriver_mapping_icis_ihs.xlsx')
ramen.head()


for col in ramen[['item_composition_in_english','formula_composition_list','composition_icis_index_matches','composition_ihs_index_matches']]:
    ramen[col] = ramen[col].str.strip()
    print('Number of unique values in ' + str(col) +': ' + str(ramen[col].nunique()))
```

I have not finding any solution to my requirements. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You should provide an example dataset and the expected output to give the possibility to run tests.

Comment: @mozway I have edited the question. I have number of data but I have given only one row example here.

Comment: See my answer. If you need something more elaborate, please edit you question to give more data and details.

Comment: @mozway Yes I have included an example sheet and mentioned the expected output there. Please check once. Thank you

Comment: The first line in your file doesn't match your previous example ("Pentaerythritol" is no longer in column A). Is this normal? Also, for the second line you have "Phenol , Naphtha" in column A and the individual items "Naphtha" and "Phenol" in B/D repectively. Should the combined "Phenol , Naphtha" be treated as one item or two items?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code. This creates two sets and calculates the difference. Of note, the order of the items is not necessarily conserved. If this is an issue, there are alternatives, but I find this approach quite minimalist and efficient.

```
ramen = pd.DataFrame([['Stearic acid ; zinc ; Pentaerythritol', 'Pentaerythritol', None]], columns=['item_composition', 'A', 'B'])
ramen

def check_items(s):
    items = s['item_composition'].split(' ; ')
    ref_items = s.drop('item_composition')
    return ' ; '.join(set(items)-set(ref_items))

ramen.apply(check_items, axis=1)
```

input:

```
                        item_composition                A     B
0  Stearic acid ; zinc ; Pentaerythritol  Pentaerythritol  None
```

output:

```
0    zinc ; Stearic acid
```

Edit: here is an updated version to input files similar to the one you provided (I imagine that the comment is not present, nor the "formuale missing indices" columns), and to export the output as xlsx with the extra column

```
def check_items(s, col='formula_composition_list', ref_columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']):
    import re
    items = re.split(' *; *', s[col])
    ref_items = s[ref_columns].dropna().str.strip()
    return ' ; '.join(set(items)-set(ref_items))

files = ['example.xlsx'] ## add other files in list
                         ## or use another way to list files
                         ## such as the glob module

for f in files:
    df = pd.read_excel(f)
    df['formulae_missing_indices'] = df.apply(check_items, axis=1)
    df.to_excel(f[:-5]+'_out.xlsx')
```

Comment: Thank you but cant we take datasets from xls and get the output. We are checking values from item_composition to A and B column. Suppose I have hundreds of data like this then above method will not be suitable right.

Comment: Do you mean that you have multiple files to process? Then you need to loop over them, apply the method, and eventually output the result to file.
If this is the case, please amend you question to add this information and provide an example xlsx file.